# High CPU usage - simple packet receiver on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, cpu-usage

I'm writing simple application under Linux that gathers all packets from network. I'm using blocking receiving by calling "recvfrom()" function. When I generate big network load with hping3 (~100k raw frames per second, 130 bytes each) "top" tool shows high CPU usage for my process - it is about 37-38%. It is big value for me. When I decrease number of packets, usage is lower - for example top shows 3% for 4k frames per second.
 
I've check DC++ when it downloads ~10MB/s and its process doesn't use 38% of CPU but 5%. Is there any programmable way in C to reduce CPU usage and still receive a lot of frames?

My CPU: 
Intel i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10Ghz

My system:
Ubuntu 11.04 kernel 3.6.6 with PREEMPT-RT patch

And here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_arp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

/* Socket descriptor. */
int mainSocket; 

/* Buffer for frame. */
unsigned char* buffer;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /** Create socket. **/  
    mainSocket = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if (mainSocket == -1) { 
        printf("Error: cannot create socket!\n");
    }

    /** Create buffer for frame **/
    buffer = malloc(ETH_FRAME_LEN);

    printf("Listing...");

    while(1) {

        // Length of received packet
        int length = recvfrom(mainSocket, buffer, ETH_FRAME_LEN, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if(length > 0) 
        {   
            // ... do something ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will help, but looking on Google I see that:

- [Raw socket, Packet socket and Zero copy networking in Linux](http://yusufonlinux.blogspot.fr/2010/11/data-link-access-and-zero-copy.html) as well as http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt talk about using `PACKET_MMAP` and `mmap()` to improve the performance of raw sockets
- The [Overview of Packet Reception](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-network-packet-reception.html) suggests setting your process's affinity to match the CPU to which you [bind the NIC using RPS](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/main-network.html#s-network-future).

Does `DC++` do a promiscuous receive? I wouldn't have guessed so. So instead of comparing your performance to `DC++`, perhaps you should compare your performance to the performance of a utility like `libpcap`.

Comment: Yes, it should be useful, especially mmap() func. I will check it and I'll give info about results soon.

Comment: Finally, I've implemented mmap(), main loop is working now on simple poll() function (I used this example http://www.scaramanga.co.uk/code-fu/lincap.c) and it gives me only ~4% boost when I'm receiving 100k frames per second. My application is depended on number of interrupts which are generated by NIC. I'm still thinking how to improve my code..

Answer (score 0):

May be because, TCP/IP stack running on NIC and DC++ is getting stream of data directly from NIC, so your processor is not doing any TCP/IP work. But in your case I think you are directly trying to get data from NIC, so it will not be processed by NIC but by your processor, and as you have infinite loop to fetch data, you doing lot of processing... so CPU usage spiked.